# Why there is no ES2018, ES2019 in caniuse.com

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next, ecma

Title seems to be self explanatory, I can see ES5 there, but there are no versions above that one.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When searching for EcmaScript 8 or 7, you don't get any results because they simply had not added ES7 and ES8 in the database.

With [a quick search](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/search?q=es7&type=Issues) in the issues we find that there are a couple of proposals, but so far they are not accepted.

[According to this discussion](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/1871) we can understand they want to focus on specific features (e.g. `async/await`) rather than on versions.

Comment: it returns same table as 'ECMA Script 5', using es7 es8 es9 es10 still don't return anything - why is that? that's my question :)